# fieldset tag presented differently in IE10 vs. older versions

Tags: html, internet-explorer-10, fieldset

The following Html snippet looks different on IE10 vs. older versions:

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
<fieldset style="position:absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 200px; height: 30px;">
<label>text1</label>
</fieldset>
<label style="position:absolute;width:65px;line-height:15px;height:15px;left:0px;top:40;">text2</label>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

IE10:

[image: IE10]

IE8:

[image: IE8]

Set aside the font changes, how can I change the page so that the layout is the same as in IE8 in both browsers ?

Comment: have you tried using IE conditional tags to choose a different style depending on the browser version?

Comment: I'd like to avoid conditional tags

Comment: looks like you've got some padding and/or margin that needs to be normalised.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `padding: 0px` seems to fix the problem, the page is now rendered the same way on all versions of IE.

The fieldset tag now looks like this:

```
<fieldset style="position:absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 200px; height: 30px; padding: 0px">
```

Comment: general rule when designing for multiple browsers is to use a reset.css file or just make your own one. I general just do *{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;}. You will avoid problems like this from occuring again